# This operation returned because the timeout period expired - unable to add third node to existing Windows Failover Cluster

Tags: clustering, windows-server, failover, failover-cluster-instance

I have a Windows failover cluster up and running, with two nodes.

I'm now trying to add a third node:

```
Add-ClusterNode -Name node3
```

this unfortunately fails with the following error:

> The clustered role was not successfully created.
> Add-ClusterNode : An error occured while performing the operation.
> This operation returned because the timeout period expired.

The server `node3` is joined to the domain like the other two instances, and all instances can talk to each other.

What could be causing this? I'm working with Windows server 2019 on EC2 (AWS)

I'm also seeing this error message when adding the node via cluster manager:

> * Cluster service on node node3 did not reach the running state. The error code is 0x5ba

Comment: I'm sure there's a log somewhere that might have helpful information.

Comment: @mustaccio which one? I've not seen any helpful message in the cluster logs

Comment: Windows Event Log and SQL Server Log are places you can check. Also, did you verify it's not a firewall issue?...can you ping the third node?

Comment: @J.D. yes, like I said all servers can talk to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a DNS issue on the node.

I had to run this for it to work:

```
Set-DnsClientGlobalSetting -SuffixSearchList @("")
```